# JavaScript component to visualize data as circles in a timeline

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for a JavaScript component which provides data circles in a timeline, something like this :

[image]

So when the user hover over each circle he receives details of each step.

Is there any component for kinda stuff ?

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely create this using [D3](https://d3js.org/). In fact, you might be able to use the [d3-timeline](https://github.com/jiahuang/d3-timeline) plugin, that can be configured to use circles.